# How to select the element of the list sequentially in R without apply and for loop

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list and would like to select the element of the list sequentially (one after one) and plug it in the function. Here is my code where I plug each element manually. How can I do that automatically without using `apply` functions or `for` loop. That is, how to select `[[1]]` then `[[2]]`.

```
mu1 <- list(2,3,4)
sd1 <- list(0.5,0.6,0.7)
w <- c(0.5,0.2,0.3)
set.seed(123)
mylist <- list(rnorm(10,mu1[[1]],sd1[[1]]),
rnorm(10,mu1[[2]],sd1[[2]]),
rnorm(10,mu1[[3]],sd1[[3]]))
ta <- list(c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.65,0.2,0.9,0.1),c(0.4,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.65,0.2,0.8,0.3),
           c(0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.25,0.2,0.6,0.4))
xx <- sum(ta[[1]]*(log(w[1])+dnorm(mylist[[1]],log=T)),ta[[2]]*(log(w[2])+dnorm(mylist[[2]],log = T)),ta[[3]]*
      (log(w[3])+dnorm(mylist[[3]],log = T)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `for` loop

```
lst <- vector('list', length(ta))
for(i in seq_along(ta)) {
  lst[[i]] <-   sum(ta[[i]]*(log(w[i])+dnorm(mylist[[i]],log=TRUE)))

 }
xx1 <- sum(unlist(lst))
identical(xx, xx1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or this can be done by converting 'ta' and 'mylist' to a `matrix`

```
xx2 <- sum(do.call(rbind, ta)*(log(w)+ dnorm(do.call(rbind, mylist), log = TRUE)))
identical(xx, xx2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a *apply function, in particular `mapply`, you can do the following.

```
yy <- sum(mapply(function(x, y, z) x * (log(y)+dnorm(z,log=T)), ta, w, mylist))
yy
[1] -89.6547
```

Check that they're the same.

```
identical(yy, xx)
[1] TRUE
```